# How can I detect double-encoded MySQL columns and rows, and validate the repair?

Tags: mysql, character-set, encoding, utf-8

My database provider, bless their hearts, migrated our MySQL databases to another server recently, and introduced double-encoding of UTF-8 data via Latin1 into our text data. Strings like 'emdash—here' became 'emdashâ€”here'. 'ellipsis…' became 'ellipsisâ€¦'. 'her’s' (with curly right single quote) became 'herâ€™s'. 'Euro €' became 'Euro â‚¬'. Affected columns had data types like `TEXT` and `VARCHAR`, in tables with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`, before and after the migration.

Live websites use some of the databases, which may therefore have user data submitted since the migration. That means some columns will have some pre-migration rows which have double-encoded text, and also some post-migration rows which will have correctly encoded UTF-8 text. Fortunately, all of the websites are lightly used, and so there won't be much correctly-encoded recent text. But there probably is some.

Now the problem of double-encoding, and the SQL queries to repair it, have been covered many times [on this site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33369/169080) and [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348228/1099571). See below for a summary. That is not my question.

What I would like is:

1. A MySQL query which tells me which columns of which tables of which databases on this server are of text types which are vulnerable to double-encoding. Columns of type `VARCHAR` are vulnerable. Columns of type `INT` are not.
2. A MySQL query which tells me which of the vulnerable text-type columns actually have content which needs repair. Columns with zero rows do not need repair. Rows with `NULL` values or zero-length strings do not need repair. Nor do rows which have only character values from 0 to 127, which are the same in UTF-8 and Latin1 encodings.
3. A MySQL query which tells me which of the vulnerable text-type columns are safe to repair by `ALTER TABLE MODIFY` queries which affect all rows, and which have some rows which are double-encoded and others which are not — and so must be repaired selectively.
4. A MySQL query which validates that the repairs were successful, that all rows of all vulnerable columns show as having been repaired successfully. I want to use this query before pushing the repaired databases live. One kind of failure I worry about is that the repair operation, on uncorrupted UTF-8 text, might turn some characters into '?' or some rows into `NULL` values. That would lose data. I want to be sure that has not happened.
5. MySQL queries which automate the process of copying a live database to a backup, doing the changes, validating the result; and other queries which make the repaired database the live one. I imagine doing the repairs by taking the websites they support offline for the duration of the repair. I want the tasks automated so that the offline interval is shorter, and the chance of stupid mistakes lower.

I figure I am not the first person to have double-encoded data. Others have probably written these queries. I have not seem them on this website, however. If I end up writing them myself, I will post them as an answer here.

P.S. Useful reading about the double-encoding problem and fixes in MySQL:

- [Debugging Character Set Issues by Example](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/debugging-character-set-issues-by-example/), Posted on Jun 13, 2017 by Bernt Marius Johnsen, MySQL Blog Archive.
- [Reply to *Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1099571), July 14, 2016 by Rick James.
- [*MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual*, 12.11 **Cast Functions and Operators**, **Character Set Conversions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#cast-character-set-conversions)
- [*MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual*, 13.1.9 **ALTER TABLE Statement**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)
- [*MySQL Charset/Collate*, **Diagnosing CHARSET issues**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues) by Rick James

For reference, I can repair a selection of rows in a column with a query like,

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET
    post_title=CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(post_title USING latin1) AS binary) USING utf8),
    post_content=CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(post_content USING latin1) AS binary) USING utf8)
WHERE ...[selection expression here]...
```

and I can update all rows in a column with a query like,

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_title` text NOT NULL CHARSET latin1,
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_content` longtext NOT NULL CHARSET latin1 ;
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_title` text NOT NULL CHARSET binary,
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_content` longtext NOT NULL CHARSET binary ;
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_title` text NOT NULL CHARSET utf8mb4,
    MODIFY COLUMN `post_content` longtext NOT NULL CHARSET utf8mb4 ;
```

But to use these queries, I need to know which columns of which databases on my server to modify, and which of the rows need repair, and which are not double-encoded so "repair" would corrupt them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the bytes in each column of each table.  *Do not trust displaying the output; browsers, especially, will "fix" the rendering of the output.*

Follow the guidelines here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases  You seem to be suggesting the 2-step ALTER.  It assumes the column has "CHARACTER SET latin1, but has utf8 bytes in it"

To discuss specific cases, please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so we can discuss whether it is simply Mojobake, double-encoding, or (rarely) triple-encoding, or even some other gibberish.

You can use the following to check a few cases on a column via

```
SELECT col, HEX(col)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '(..)*[89a-fA-F]'
    LIMIT 5;
```

You can use a `SELECT` against `information_schema.COLUMNS` to generate such Selects for each text column in your system.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, and for your earlier answer to which I linked in the question. I did dump the hex values of the code units of the corrupted text. It is indeed a case of double-encoding: text encoded as UTF-8 in the old database, those code units (bytes) interpreted as latin 1, decoded into characters, those characters stored in the new database as UTF-8. I could add the byte sequences to the question if that would help, but I am confident in my diagnosis of double-encoding via Latin1.

Comment: Also, HEX(col) REGEXP '...' is a brilliant idea for exploring the actual encoding of text content!